# How to display list of items in a table in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reletevly new in React/JS programming. I can't underestand what is the problem of my code. I have a column and I want to add row in it based on number of items in my Array. However, at the end, only header of my table displays.

So, I am wondering what is my mistake? I am able to see following output in logs:

```
BodyComponent.jsx:55 1. Title One
BodyComponent.jsx:55 2. Title Two
BodyComponent.jsx:55 3. Title Three
```

This is my class:

```
const testList = [
    { title: 'Title One', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Title Two', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Title Three', id: 3 }
]

class BodyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            /* <!-- Main container --> */
            <nav className="level body-container">
                {/* <!-- Left side --> */}
                <div className="level-left">
                    <div className="level-item">
                        This is left
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* <!-- Right side --> */}
                <div className="level-right">
                    <div className="level-item">
                        {sideBarPanel(testList)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

const sideBarPanel = (itemList) => {
    return (
        <nav className="panel body-sidebar">
            <p className="panel-heading sidebar-title">
                List of letters
            </p>

            {
                itemList.forEach((it) => {
                        panelItem(it)
                    }
                )
            }
        </nav>
    )
}

const panelItem = (item) => {
    return (
        <a className="panel-block">
            {item.id + '. ' + item.title}
            {console.log(item.id + '. ' + item.title)}
        </a>
    )
}

export default BodyComponent
```

Comment: you need to use map , forEach dosen't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [rendering lists in ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components): the goal is to `return` an `array` of `components`.

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is typically used over [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as the latter `returns` nothing.

`Array` `children` also require unique [`key` `props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) when doing so.

See below for a practical example.

```
// Side Bar Panel.
const SideBarPanel = (itemList) => (
  <nav className="panel body-sidebar">
    <p className="panel-heading sidebar-title"> List of letters </p>
    {itemList.map((it, i) => <PanelItem key={i} id={it.id} title={it.title}/>}
  </nav>
)

// Panel Item.
const PanelItem = props => <a className="panel-block">{props.id}. {props.title}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I learnt new things from your sample code. Also, I noticed that I have to rename `panelItem` to `PanelItem` otherwise I get error.